# If $A$ is a closed operator, is $A^k$ closed?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, unbounded-operators

Let $A$ be a closed (densely defined) operator on a Hilbert space $H$.

We define for a natural number $k$, the operator $A^k$ with its natural domain.

Is $A^k$ closed?

Comment: Isn't this easy? Does applying the operator $k$ times give the kth power of it?

Comment: @MaartenHavinga Yes, but how is it easy?

Comment: This question could be related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4411888/when-is-the-composition-of-unbounded-closed-operators-closed-closeable) or [this other one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4044377/is-the-composition-of-closed-unbounded-operators-closed). But the counter-example below seems to go in the other direction.

Comment: @cs89 Thanks for pointint this out! Hm, then either the counterexample below or the answer you link to contains a mistake.

Comment: @cs89: The [answer in your second link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4411950/793015) is not correct; please see my comment there.

Comment: Nice catch! Since you seem to know the subject, and suggested a sufficient condition involving the resolvent set in a comment below, you could maybe also answer [this third question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3751860/powers-of-general-closed-operators-closed) where the author suggested various possible sufficient conditions for $A^k$ to be closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a counterexample (subject perhaps to what you consider "natural").
Take a separable Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $\{u_n : n = 1, 2, \ldots\}$ and the operator $A$ defined by
$$ A u_n = \cases{ n u_{n+1} & if $n$ is odd\cr 0 & if $n$ is even}$$
with domain $D = \{x = \sum_n c_n x_n : \sum_n |c_n|^2 < \infty, \sum_{n \text{ odd}} n^2 |c_n|^2 < \infty\}$. Then $A$ is closed and densely defined.  For integers $k > 1$ I would expect the "natural" domain of $A^k$ to be  contained in $D$. However, $A^k x = 0$ where it is defined, so that $A^k$ is not closed.

Comment: +1 Nice counterexample. The same phenomenon occurs, maybe in a slightly more transparent way, if one considers a block operator $A:=\begin{pmatrix} 0&B\\0&0 \end{pmatrix}$ for a closed but unbounded operator $B$.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to add, though, that $A^k$ is indeed closed if the resolvent set of $A$ is non-empty.

Comment: @JochenGlueck: Robert's example is of this type, if one splits the space as $\ell^2=\ell^2(\{ 2n\} )\oplus\ell^2( \{2n+1\})$.

Comment: So the catch is that $A^k$ can allow for more converging sequences in its domain than $A$, leading to limits $l$ outside the domain of $A$ and of $A^k$? I assumed wrongly that the domain and image of $A$ would be the same.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: Yes, sure. I just thought the example might be a bit easier to understand (and, in particular, to remember) if one writes it down in operator matrix form and without the concrete details of $B$ (since they don't matter).